# React Native - "react-native-interface.js" - WebStorm

Tags: react-native, webstorm

For react-native - WebStorm users:

I'm starting a project with React Native using Jet Brains IDE WebStorm.

On project => node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/**react-native-interface.js**

IDE get syntax errors:

[image: react-native-interface.js syntax error print .jpg]

Am I missing some library or plugin?

Comment: Can you hover over the error to find out what the error message actually is?

Comment: it is a flow syntax. You need to enable flow integration in the settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/using-the-flow-type-checker.html

Comment: I think it's better to use [Atom](https://atom.io) with `Nuclide` when developing react-native apps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing the syntax error because WebStorm thinks the file is regular JS. However, it's actually written in Flow.

Flow eventually gets transformed into JS, similar to TypeScript. Learn more about Flow here: https://flowtype.org/

Honestly, don't worry about it unless you messing with the core files (which you shouldn't unless you're fixing bugs).

I know it's annoying to have the red squiggly lines in your project. You can just close your project and reopen it. This will remove the red squiggly lines!

If you want to enable Flow syntax, follow these steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/using-the-flow-type-checker.html

**EDIT:** A quicker hack to get the lines removed is to close the file with the error. Right click it in the project view, mark it as plain text, then remark it as a JS file. Voila! Just make sure to not open file otherwise repeat the steps. lol